# apache loads cgi on "realtime"

Tags: apache, bash, cgi, mamp, wait

I'm using one cgi server on the mamp apache's server.
When I load one script like:

echo "asd"
sleep 10
echo "dsa"
sleep 20

I need to wait 30 seconds to see the echo. It doesn't do the render per line, it seems it needs the script to load entirely to send the data back.

How can I configure to the apache returns the line, then wait the 10 secconds, print the another line and then wait?

On php if you do that the script will print and then sleep, but my bash script doesn't do that on the cgi.

If I run it with bash script.cgi it prints the line, wait, print and the wait. So it seems to be one problem with the apache.

Answer (score 0):

It's the browser's buffering.

Apache does not buffer cgi-bin scripts. It sends the line immediately to the browser.
Nothing to do on apache / script side.
May be there are some non standard HTTP header you can attach to the response to force the browser to early display the piece of page, but I don't know which.

Answer (score 0):

I found that Firefox and Chromium buffer about 1 kilobyte to heuristically determine if the output is text or binary.  For plain text you can output as many spaces, or for HTML create a sufficiently large comment.  After this, content can be progressively displayed.

In my tests, a regular CGI script did not work since Apache buffered in order to gzip the output (I used Wireshark).  Instead, I wrote a No Parsed Headers (NPH) script that handled chunked transfer encoding on its own.